# Is it possible to add tables to bucardo automatically?

Tags: postgresql, bucardo

I want all tables to be replicated by bucardo (at least for a given database), but it looks like I have to add them all manually:

```
bucardo_ctl add all tables
```

Can I have it so that every table in a database is replicated, or added to bucardo automatically?

If not, is there another replication strategy in Postgresql that might be better fit for me? I'm hoping to have all nodes available for reads/writes, to avoid administering any routing process to route the writes to the master. If the routing of writes can be done natively in Postgresql, then that could be a solution as well.

Answer (score 0):

Use below command for add all

```
bucardo add all tables
```

Comment: I think this only adds _current_ tables. I was hoping to add all tables created in the _future_, after running the command as well. If this works for that purpose, that would be great.

Comment: That is not possible i think, you need to add manually which table want to add in replication